# C# Formula (123/2*15+22) evaluation

Tags: c#

Does someone know the best way to evaluate a string formula like this one: (123/2*15+22)
within c#.

I have read that i should use an ICodeCompiled, but havent been able to find any good implementations to do this very simply thing.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Would you want `((1/2)*2)` to be 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an expression parser, such as [this one at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MathieuMathParser.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var calc = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Console.WriteLine(calc.Compute("(123/2*15+22)", ""));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: 944.5

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at MSDN's documentation on [ICodeCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.icodecompiler.aspx).

Comment: -1: I'm sorry, but this singularly unhelpful answer, you could make it marginally more helpful by providing a link to the documentation. P.s. I'll remove the downvote if you make the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem I typically recommend [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/); I've had nothing but good experiences using it to do equation evaluation and some basic DSL work.